# Make new json object by reduce key

Tags: javascript, json, methods

I have searched stack overflow for about 30 minutes but I am not sure that I can use filter, map or reduce. I have the following JSON

**Input**

```
[
  {
    "_id": "5a3711070776d02ed87d2100",
    "index": 0,
    "guid": "fb08e9c3-c5b6-44e9-a4c6-73edcfbc8ae9",
    "isActive": false,
    "balance": "$2,762.54",
    "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",
    "age": 39,
    "eyeColor": "brown",
    "name": "Crystal Sampson",
    "gender": "female",
    "company": "ZAGGLE",
    "email": "crystalsampson@zaggle.com",
    "phone": "+1 (822) 582-2186",
    "address": "836 Batchelder Street, Harviell, Indiana, 966",
    "about": "Duis eu irure mollit sit voluptate proident do reprehenderit irure sunt irure tempor. Elit commodo mollit Lorem esse elit ea nostrud. Commodo cillum ipsum enim incididunt aliquip consectetur cillum cillum commodo et aliquip.\r\n",
    "registered": "2017-01-31T09:56:39 -07:00",
    "latitude": 18.386331,
    "longitude": -3.807078,
    "tags": [
      "laboris",
      "reprehenderit",
      "aliqua",
      "ipsum",
      "in",
      "consequat",
      "anim"
    ],
    "friends": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "Lily Mullen"
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Smith Howard"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Ronda Stafford"
      }
    ],
    "greeting": "Hello, Crystal Sampson! You have 2 unread messages.",
    "favoriteFruit": "banana"
  }]
```

**Output**

```
[{"name": "Crystal Sampson",
"gender": "female",
"company": "ZAGGLE",
"email": "crystalsampson@zaggle.com"}]
```

I want to reduce key that I interest. Thank you so much.

Comment: If I interpret this correctly, then you should be able to use `.map()` to a new object with only those properties. Like: `.map(item => {name: item.name, gender: item.gender, company: item.company, email: item.email})`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is `.map` over the array and make new objects only with the keys you are interested in.

```js
const input = [
  {
    "_id": "5a3711070776d02ed87d2100",
    "index": 0,
    "guid": "fb08e9c3-c5b6-44e9-a4c6-73edcfbc8ae9",
    "isActive": false,
    "balance": "$2,762.54",
    "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",
    "age": 39,
    "eyeColor": "brown",
    "name": "Crystal Sampson",
    "gender": "female",
    "company": "ZAGGLE",
    "email": "crystalsampson@zaggle.com",
    "phone": "+1 (822) 582-2186",
    "address": "836 Batchelder Street, Harviell, Indiana, 966",
    "about": "Duis eu irure mollit sit voluptate proident do reprehenderit irure sunt irure tempor. Elit commodo mollit Lorem esse elit ea nostrud. Commodo cillum ipsum enim incididunt aliquip consectetur cillum cillum commodo et aliquip.\r\n",
    "registered": "2017-01-31T09:56:39 -07:00",
    "latitude": 18.386331,
    "longitude": -3.807078,
    "tags": [
      "laboris",
      "reprehenderit",
      "aliqua",
      "ipsum",
      "in",
      "consequat",
      "anim"
    ],
    "friends": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "Lily Mullen"
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Smith Howard"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Ronda Stafford"
      }
    ],
    "greeting": "Hello, Crystal Sampson! You have 2 unread messages.",
    "favoriteFruit": "banana"
  }];
  
  const output = input.map(element => {
    return {
      name: element.name,
      gender: element.gender,
      company: element.company,
      email: element.email
    }
  });
  
  console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple for loop for the object in the outer array then for the keys of the object to check if the key exist on the `selectedKey` array which you want to consider. Using `selectedKey` will help you to scale easily for any of the keys you want, just specify them in `selectedKey` array.

```js
var data = [
  {
    "_id": "5a3711070776d02ed87d2100",
    "index": 0,
    "guid": "fb08e9c3-c5b6-44e9-a4c6-73edcfbc8ae9",
    "isActive": false,
    "balance": "$2,762.54",
    "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",
    "age": 39,
    "eyeColor": "brown",
    "name": "Crystal Sampson",
    "gender": "female",
    "company": "ZAGGLE",
    "email": "crystalsampson@zaggle.com",
    "phone": "+1 (822) 582-2186",
    "address": "836 Batchelder Street, Harviell, Indiana, 966",
    "about": "Duis eu irure mollit sit voluptate proident do reprehenderit irure sunt irure tempor. Elit commodo mollit Lorem esse elit ea nostrud. Commodo cillum ipsum enim incididunt aliquip consectetur cillum cillum commodo et aliquip.\r\n",
    "registered": "2017-01-31T09:56:39 -07:00",
    "latitude": 18.386331,
    "longitude": -3.807078,
    "tags": [
      "laboris",
      "reprehenderit",
      "aliqua",
      "ipsum",
      "in",
      "consequat",
      "anim"
    ],
    "friends": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "Lily Mullen"
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Smith Howard"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Ronda Stafford"
      }
    ],
    "greeting": "Hello, Crystal Sampson! You have 2 unread messages.",
    "favoriteFruit": "banana"
  }];
  
var selectedKey = ['name','company','gender', 'email'];

var res = [];
data.forEach((obj)=>{
  Object.keys(obj).forEach((key)=>{
    if(selectedKey.indexOf(key) !== -1){
      var tempObj = {};
      tempObj[key] = obj[key]
      res.push(tempObj);
    }
  });
});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do some sort of filter like this:

```js
var input = [{
  "_id": "5a3711070776d02ed87d2100",
  "index": 0,
  "guid": "fb08e9c3-c5b6-44e9-a4c6-73edcfbc8ae9",
  "isActive": false,
  "balance": "$2,762.54",
  "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",
  "age": 39,
  "eyeColor": "brown",
  "name": "Crystal Sampson",
  "gender": "female",
  "company": "ZAGGLE",
  "email": "crystalsampson@zaggle.com",
  "phone": "+1 (822) 582-2186",
  "address": "836 Batchelder Street, Harviell, Indiana, 966",
  "about": "Duis eu irure mollit sit voluptate proident do reprehenderit irure sunt irure tempor. Elit commodo mollit Lorem esse elit ea nostrud. Commodo cillum ipsum enim incididunt aliquip consectetur cillum cillum commodo et aliquip.\r\n",
  "registered": "2017-01-31T09:56:39 -07:00",
  "latitude": 18.386331,
  "longitude": -3.807078,
  "tags": [
    "laboris",
    "reprehenderit",
    "aliqua",
    "ipsum",
    "in",
    "consequat",
    "anim"
  ],
  "friends": [{
      "id": 0,
      "name": "Lily Mullen"
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Smith Howard"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Ronda Stafford"
    }
  ],
  "greeting": "Hello, Crystal Sampson! You have 2 unread messages.",
  "favoriteFruit": "banana"
}];
console.log(input.map(function (item) {
  return {
    name: item.name,
    gender: item.gender,
    company: item.company,
    email: item.email
  };
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

For your question, i have used map function to iterate over your array.

Google more about difference between map, filter and reduce. You'll get fantastic examples. And try them on your own.

```
var arrResult = [];

var InputObject = [{
"_id": "5a3711070776d02ed87d2100",
"index": 0,
"guid": "fb08e9c3-c5b6-44e9-a4c6-73edcfbc8ae9",
"isActive": false,
"balance": "$2,762.54",
"picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",
"age": 39,
"eyeColor": "brown",
"name": "Crystal Sampson",
"gender": "female",
"company": "ZAGGLE",
"email": "crystalsampson@zaggle.com",
"phone": "+1 (822) 582-2186",
"address": "836 Batchelder Street, Harviell, Indiana, 966",
"about": "Duis eu irure mollit sit voluptate proident do reprehenderit irure sunt irure tempor. Elit commodo mollit Lorem esse elit ea nostrud. Commodo cillum ipsum enim incididunt aliquip consectetur cillum cillum commodo et aliquip.\r\n",
"registered": "2017-01-31T09:56:39 -07:00",
"latitude": 18.386331,
"longitude": -3.807078,
"tags": [
  "laboris",
  "reprehenderit",
  "aliqua",
  "ipsum",
  "in",
  "consequat",
  "anim"
],
"friends": [
  {
    "id": 0,
    "name": "Lily Mullen"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Smith Howard"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Ronda Stafford"
  }
],
"greeting": "Hello, Crystal Sampson! You have 2 unread messages.",
"favoriteFruit": "banana"}];


InputObject.map((x)=>{
    var obj = {
        "name": x.name,
        "gender": x.gender,
        "company": x.company,
        "email": x.email
    };
    arrResult.push(obj);
});

console.log(arrResult);
```

Comment: This is an invalid usage of `map`. You basically use it just to loop as a `forEach()`. This can be simplified to return a obj inside of the map function. Take a look at other answers

Answer (score 0):

Is a document from collection in MongoDB really?? Why not use [projections](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/)?

If don't want use projections you have another alternative, remember, a JSON is a Object, so:

```js
var obj = new Object(); 
obj['XKey1'] = "Value1";
obj['XKey2'] = "Value2";
obj['YKey3'] = "Value3";
obj['YKey4'] = "Value4";


Object.keys(obj).map(function(objectKey, index) {
  if(objectKey=='YKey3') delete obj[objectKey];
});

console.log(obj)
```